# Web Fonts not showing up

Tags: html, css

For some reason, I can not get my fonts to appear on the page. I am opening this up from a static page on my computer. The html, css and fonts are all in the same folder.  I have tried adding "./" and "/" in front of the the font location, but it did not work. The CSS file is loading. Thoughts?

## font.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'American-Typewriter';
    src: url('american-typewriter.eot');
    src: url('american-typewriter.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('american-typewriter.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('american-typewriter.woff') format('woff'),
         url('american-typewriter.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('american-typewriter.svg#american_typewriterregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.American-Typewriter {
    font-family: 'American-Typewriter';
}
```

## webpage.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font.css">
    </head>    
<body>
         <h1 class='American-Typewriter'> American-Typewriter   </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Any reason you are not browsing to it as a website? I'm suspicious that if you're opening from a static page, that could be part of the issue.... I strongly recommend using [Font Squirrel]() to generate your font package / includes.... they don't have American Typewriter, but it appears that's not actually a public-domain font, which could _also_ be part of the problem....

Comment: Can you expand on a font not being a public domain font and how that creates an issue?

Comment: "Public domain" - free, not licensed.  My research shows that it _may_ be a licensed font, which would mean that places that permit you to download it free are using some sort of bootlegged copy / version.  Which would potentially cause problems....

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem with addressing.
Try using only /

Comment: The css file is loading, as I see the CSS in the elements on inspection, but the font does not show.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first use  code in your code in order to have standard HTML as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font.css">
</head>
<body>
     <h1 class='American-Typewriter'> American-Typewriter   </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Also you need to download the font if you still not able to see it from below link.

http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/American-Typewriter-Regular

Comment: I added the head tag, and I have the web-fonts in my folder, but still does not work.

Comment: that was typo, i mean to say use below code in your page, but if you already have it send me your zip containing css, html and font so that i can check and reply back.

Comment: What browser version you are using as it only support few of latest version browsers and not all.

Answer (score 0):

If they're in the same folder, then you don't need anything before the filename!

`/` is used when the object you're looking for is in a folder, and `../` is used when it's in the folder enclosing the current folder, e.g. the one the file is in.